# How to define the message content in Apache log?

Tags: apache2, logging

I want to add some useful message, such as user id and session key-value, into each message in Apache log. I google it but only found how to format the message header, i.e. log time, remote IP, local IP. All the content of message in Apache log is request URL.
I wonder there is any method to define the message's content. Does Apache server provide some plugins for this usage?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`mod_log_config`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html) and its `CustomLog` directive.

You should be able to log the session ID using the `%..C` directive. There is also a [`CookieLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#cookielog).

Comment: I have checked out mod_log_config. If I keep user ID in cookie, '%..C' will work. What can I do if the message doesn't exist in cookie, do you think '%..e' will help me? I can set some environment parameter in my web application, then got it and log.

Comment: @Roy that might work! I'd be interested to hear whether it did.